# adding new checkboxes

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add a new checkbox for each String in alist.

The code is:

```
void MainFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ArrayList alist = new ArrayList();
            alist.Add("First");
            alist.Add("Second");

            foreach (String s in alist) {

// add new checkbox with different name for each string in alist

            }

        }
```

please help

Comment: This question doesn't have enough detail to be answerable. I'm assuming this is WinForms? Please verify. Also, if you haven't done so, read http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 ArrayList alist = new ArrayList();
        alist.Add("First");
        alist.Add("Second");

        int loopCount=1;
        foreach (String s in alist)
        {

            // add new checkbox with different name for each string in alist
            CheckBox c = new CheckBox();
            c.Name = s;
            c.Text = s;
            c.Parent = this;
            c.Visible = true;

            //position the checkbox
            c.Top = loopCount*c.Height;

            this.Controls.Add(c);
            loopCount++;


        }
```

hope that helps.

Comment: I don't mind being marked down but I'd like to know why.

Comment: REDYEYEMONSTER's answer for the win !!!

Answer (score 1):

This at least should get you started:

```
foreach (String s in alist) 
{            
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
    cb.Text = s;
    this.Controls.Add(cb);
}
```

Comment: I used that it only adds the first not the rest

Comment: You're going to want to change the location during each iteration as well, otherwise they will appear on top of each other. (As I said that was just to get you started).

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically add controls using the `Controls` collection of the form. The `i` is used to make sure the positions of the checkboxes do not overlap excessively.

```
int i = 0;
foreach (String s in alist) 
{
    CheckBox myCheckBox = new CheckBox();
    myCheckBox.Name = s;
    myCheckBox.Text = s;
    myCheckBox.Size = new Size(74, 13);
    myCheckBox.Location = new Point(138, i);
    this.Controls.Add(myCheckBox);
    i = i + 18;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the names be the same?

Comment: Thank you Justin.. half of the text is cut off however

Answer (score 0):

Create an object of `CheckBox`  class and set the `Name` property value and Add it to the `Controls` Collection of any of the Container element. You need to set the Position of each newly created checkboxes different otherwise it will all sit at one place (one on top of the other) and you wont be able to see it all.

```
int top = 10;
foreach (String s in alist)
{
    top = top + 10;
    var chk = new CheckBox();
    chk.Name = s;
    chk.Top=top;  
    groupBox1.Controls.Add(chk);

}
```

Here i am adding the newly created checkboxes to a `GroupBox` control with name groupBox1.